# Vector space with exactly one basis

Tags: linear-algebra

If $0$ denotes the zero vector in some vector space $V$. We know that {$0$} is a one dimensional vector space whose basis is the $0$ vector itself. But wouldn't any other vector $v$ from $V$ also form a basis of {$0$}? Because the $0$ vector is in the span of $v$.

Then, is there a vector space with exactly one basis?

Edit: Working over the field of real and complex numbers only.

Comment: A one dimensional space over $\Bbb F_2$ (invalidated after the edit).

Comment: @WhatsUp I forgot to mention that we working over the field of real and complex numbers only. I edited the post now.

Comment: Also, by the way, in the vector space $\{0\}$ it is _not_ "officially" the case that the $0$-vector is a basis, for several definitional-technicality-type reasons. Rather, officially, the unique basis for $\{0\}$ is the empty set of vectors. And then there's @WhatsUp's example. :)

Comment: $\{0\}$ is _zero_ dimensional and its basis is not $\{0\}$ but $\emptyset$.

Comment: I agree with @Magdiragdag: the unique basis for the zero vector space is the empty set. Note that $\{0\}$ is always a linearly dependent set of vectors, so cannot be a basis.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about the empty set. Thanks everyone!